# I thought curtime(), now() and current_timestamp are valid default datetime values in MySql?

Tags: mysql, datetime, default-value

I'm using the latest version of MySql and I tried altering a table to use curtime() or now() or current_timestamp as the default value for a datetime column (created_at, updated_at). For all three, the alter failed, saying these are invalid default values. Any ideas what's an appropriate default value to generate the current time in a datetime field?

```
ALTER TABLE `music_library_development`.`albums` 
MODIFY COLUMN `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp,
MODIFY COLUMN `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp;

ALTER TABLE `music_library_development`.`albums` 
MODIFY COLUMN `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
MODIFY COLUMN `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT now();

ALTER TABLE `music_library_development`.`albums` 
MODIFY COLUMN `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT curtime(),
MODIFY COLUMN `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT curtime();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html) column type:

```
MODIFY COLUMN `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp;
```

Comment: I just tried that. It says there can only be one timestamp column with a default value set.

Comment: Yes, you can't have multiple columns that auto update.  This was addressed on another question, but I can't find it.

Comment: But that's kinda not done, because most audited records will have created_at and updated_at fields whose value is set during record creation

Answer (score 0):

alter table music_library_development change created_at created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

alter table music_library_development change updated_at updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP